# How to perform Inner Join in Pandas with a function/condition/regex?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, inner-join

I want to achieve in Pandas something what I achieve with such an SQL query:

```
SELECT kwh_report.date, site_aftagenr.site_id, kwh_report.kwh FROM mydb.kwh_report 
INNER JOIN mydb.site_aftagenr ON 2sniff.site_aftagenr.aftagenr = RIGHT(mydb.kwh_report.cell, LENGTH(mydb.site_aftagenr.aftagenr))
```

In Pandas I have following dataframes:

```
aftagenr    site_id
0   101401720001   FASDG
1   4601407834     JHDWD
2   3103341806     JBPIS
3   4601215118     JWPDL
4   4601413279     J8STA
...
```

```
cell    date    kwh
0   561314101401720001  00:00:00 01-06-2020 2.1
1   561314101401720001  01:00:00 01-06-2020 2.1
2   561314101401720001  02:00:00 01-06-2020 2.2
3   561314101401720001  03:00:00 01-06-2020 2.1
...
```

I want to replace *cell* value with a corresponding *site_id*. *Cell* values end with *aftagern* but lengths can differ. I cannot find a way to perform inner join on something which is not simply a column.